# SQL Connection with C++ error fetching

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server

So, I got a simple connection to SQL Server, it connects fine, and execute sql fine too, it returns me the first row, but than when it hit the Fetch again it throws this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x011219A0 in JangadaServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
```

code:

```
bool database::connect()
{
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
        return false;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,     (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
        return false;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
        return false;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)TEXT("DRIVER=SQL       Server;SERVER=.\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=jangadares;UID=sa;PWD=******;Trusted_Connection=no;"),
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)){
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
    case SQL_ERROR:
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

bool database::verify_account(char* account, char* password)
{
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
        return false;
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, (SQLWCHAR*)TEXT("select * from accounts"), SQL_NTS)){
        show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        char account[50];
        char password[50];
        int id;
        while (SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle) == SQL_SUCCESS){
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_UBIGINT, &id, 0, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, account, 50, NULL);
            SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, password, 50, NULL);
            std::string acc = account;
            acc.erase(remove_if(acc.begin(), acc.end(), isspace), acc.end());
            std::string pwd = password;
            pwd.erase(remove_if(pwd.begin(), pwd.end(), isspace), pwd.end());
            printf("%d", id);
            printf(acc.c_str());
            printf(pwd.c_str());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know what to do, since it returns the first row okay, and it only got one row, so I guess I should handle these error or what?

Comment: Did you debug this code? On what line does it crash?

Comment: It crashes at the second time it pass here "while (SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle) == SQL_SUCCESS){" the first one is fine, it prints all good, but when it goes at SQLFetch again, to get anothers rows, it crashes